# Position background-image based on percentage of image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am looking for a (CSS only) solution to position an image (a `background-image` on a `<div>`) based on a percentage value of the image dimensions, not the dimensions of the element.

For example if I use the following: `background-position: 50% 50%` this will center the image in the `<div>`, but what I really want to do is have the the 50% mark of the image for both x and y axis (middle of the image) at the left and top of the `<div>` respectively. This works as expected when doing `background-position: 0% 0%` as this will align the left of the image with the left of the `<div>` (and top of image with top of `<div>`). But as detailed [here](https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/) there appears to be some interesting calculations going on when interpreting those percentage values for `background-position`.

---

Here are some examples:

Not what I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/j4etsg8w/

The result I want (but should use percentages not absolute pixel values):
https://jsfiddle.net/qgp4sfdm/

This is only an example and the images I am using will not always have a 1:1 scale ratio to the `<div>`. For example, this is what it should look like with a 2000x1000 image: https://jsfiddle.net/uxvjgtra/

---

I know I can do this using JS by requesting the actual size of the image, then figuring out how it's been scaled to fit the `<div>` then manually positioning accordingly - but the problem is that I want to be able to apply this transformation *before* the image loads (to avoid a jarring image transformation when the page loads), and I won't have access to the actual image dimensions until the image does load...so that's why I want to use CSS.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this? Maybe some trick with CSS `calc()`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the end goal, you could apply the background to a pseudo element of the parent, make the pseudo element match the size of the parent, then use `translate()` to move it up/left 50% of it's own width/height.

```css
.myImage {  
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.myImage::before {
  content: '';
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000) 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="myImage">

</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting - ideally I'd like not to use pseudo elements as that might have the potential to open up another can of worms...although maybe not. I don't think this quite solves the problem though. See https://jsfiddle.net/2tqfcmw2/ as I mentioned in my question, the image will not always fit the `<div>` 1:1 - sorry maybe my example was a little misleading.

Comment: @abagshaw not sure if I fully understand the end goal. You can just make the pseudo element the same size as the image https://jsfiddle.net/2tqfcmw2/1/

Comment: The point is, I don't know the size of the image. If I did, I could use JS as I mentioned in my question. That's why I'm wanting to use percentage values. I know that I want say the 40% x axis mark of the image aligned with the left of the div (so the left 40% of the image is hidden) but I don't know if it's 1000px, 2000px, or 10000px wide.

Comment: @abagshaw hmm... I don't know how you would do that. using a pseudo element is the only way I can think of it, and then you would need either the size of the image or the ratio of the height / width, which is based on the size of the image, and you won't know that. I dunno if that's possible. It's obviously possible as an `img` tho, but I'm assuming that isn't an option? If my answer isn't helpful, I can delete it if you like.

Comment: Actually I do know the ratio of the height/width - just not the exact dimensions in pixels. How would that help? Thanks for all your help with this - really appreciate it!

Comment: @abagshaw that ratio will allow you to create the height/width of the pseudo element without specifying the height/width. Divide the height by the width and multiply by 100 to get the ratio as a percentage, and apply that as a vertical padding to the element to make the element the same ratio as the image. Unfortunately the pseudo element won't match the exact size of the image, but it will match the ratio, and the width will be based off of whatever parent element has a non-static `position`. https://jsfiddle.net/2tqfcmw2/2/

Comment: Hmm yeah I'm in unfamiliar territory here, but I have a feeling this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to keep poking around to see if a simpler solution shows up...but I understand it probably won't. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: Your point about using ratios helped me find a workaround for this (using JS though). Upvoted, but not going to mark as answer in case any other ideas come along. Thanks again!

Comment: @abagshaw sweet! can you show me what you ended up doing? and can you show me the actual use case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150118/discussion-between-abagshaw-and-michael-coker).